# How i can modify the built in registration form of laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to EDIT , DELETE , UPDATE the laravel 5.5 built in form , Please anyone tell me about routes and idea how to get and edit the laravel 5.5 built in Registration form? 
I have completed edit , update , delete in custom users , but i want to apply CRUD on the built in laravel 5.5 Registration form? Thanks Developers in advance.

Comment: what do you want to do more precisely ?

Comment: Leo i want to modify the registered user , because we use the laravel built in registration form using :auth command , but i have no access or found a route to edit the user delete the user in this form? How can i modify users

Comment: okay if you go to App\Http\Controllers\Auth you have Login and Register Controllers you can modify them there. Or if you want to modify the blades you go to resources/views/auth/ there you find the registration/login blades ?

Comment: Okk Sir you are great and superb Leo , And thanks i found this solution , bundle of thanks Sir LeoKelmendi

Comment: I am actually update the result and record in the homecontroller , but not changes in the Auth login and registration users , now we modify in the Auth controllers , thanks sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay if you go to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` you have Login and Register Controllers you can modify them there. If you want to edit the login or register proces you proppably want to go to authenticatable laravel trait.

Or if you want to modify the blades you go to `resources/views/auth/` there you find the `registration/login` blades.

For more laravel structure follow this : [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/structure)